How to decode a protobuf Firestore event payload
I have a Cloud Run Function, that gets triggered on google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.written Firestore event, as outlined below:
from cloudevents.http import CloudEvent
import functions_framework
from google.events.cloud import firestore
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict

@functions_framework.cloud_event
def hello_firestore(cloud_event: CloudEvent) -> None:
    """Triggers by a change to a Firestore document.
    Args:
        cloud_event: cloud event with information on the firestore event trigger
    """
    firestore_payload = firestore.DocumentEventData()
    firestore_payload._pb.ParseFromString(cloud_event.data)

    # Convert protobuf to dictionary
    old_value_dict = MessageToDict(firestore_payload.old_value._pb) if firestore_payload.old_value else {}
    new_value_dict = MessageToDict(firestore_payload.value._pb) if firestore_payload.value else {}
    print(new_value_dict)
    print(old_value_dict)

However, the output seems to be in this format:
{
    "name": "projects/my-gcp-project/databases/mydb/documents/mycollection/e2767cc0-2e04-452d-9b7b-fc170e2128ec",
    "fields": {
        "created_at": {"stringValue": "2024-10-31T11:09:34.760557Z"},
        "session_id": {"stringValue": "e2767cc0-2e04-452d-9b7b-fc170e2128ec"},
        "user_profile": {
            "mapValue": {
                "fields": {
                    "age": {"integerValue": "36"},
                    "name": {"stringValue": "Andrew"},
                    "middle_name": {"nullValue": None}
                }
            }
        },
    ....
    "createTime": "2024-10-31T11:09:34.802575Z",
    "updateTime": "2024-10-31T12:13:36.154031Z",
}

How can I programmatically decode the message in order to convert everything to Python native types, in the following format:
{
  "created_at": "2024-10-31T11:09:34.760557Z",
  "session_id": "e2767cc0-2e04-452d-9b7b-fc170e2128ec",
  "user_profile": {
      "age": 36, 
      "name": "Andrew", 
      "middle_name": None,
  }
}


It's not allowed as an answer here, but I asked ChatGPT and it generated a pretty decent function to perform this conversion.

@FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your reply. So there's not out-of-the-box solution to achieve this?

It's surprising that there doesn't appear (!?) to be functionality to do this conversion in Google's libraries.
As @frank-van-puffelen suggested, the functionality is straightforward albeit tedious:
requirements.txt:
google-cloud-firestore==2.19.0
google-events==0.13.0

main.py:
from proto.marshal.collections.maps import MapComposite

from google.events.cloud.firestore import (
    Document,
    DocumentEventData,
    ArrayValue,
    MapValue,
    Value,
)


def DocumentToDict(d: Document) -> dict:
    return {
        "name": d.name,
        "fields": MapCompositeToDict(d.fields),
        "create_time": d.create_time,
        "update_time": d.update_time,
    }


def ArrayValueToList(a: ArrayValue) -> list:
    result: list = []
    for value in a.values:
        result.append(ValueToDict(value))

    return result

def MapCompositeToDict(m: MapComposite) -> dict:
    result: dict = {}
    for key, value in m.items():
        key: str
        value: Value
        result[key] = ValueToDict(value)

    return result

def ValueToDict(v: Value) -> dict:
    λs = {
        "null_value": lambda v: None,
        "boolean_value": lambda v: v.boolean_value,
        "integer_value": lambda v: v.integer_value,
        "double_value": lambda v: v.double_value,
        "timestamp_value": lambda v: v.timestamp_value,
        "string_value": lambda v: v.string_value,
        "bytes_value": lambda v: v.bytes_value,
        "reference_value": lambda v: v.reference_value,
        "geo_point_value": lambda v: v.geo_point_value,
        "array_value": lambda v: ArrayValueToList(v.array_value),
        "map_value": lambda v: MapCompositeToDict(v.map_value.fields),
    }

    type = v._pb.WhichOneof("value_type")
    λ = λs[type]
    if λ is None:
        raise ValueError(f"Unknown type: {type}")
    
    return λ(v)


data = """
{
  "name": "projects/my-gcp-project/databases/mydb/documents/mycollection/e2767cc0-2e04-452d-9b7b-fc170e2128ec",
  "fields": {
      "created_at": {"stringValue": "2024-10-31T11:09:34.760557Z"},
      "session_id": {"stringValue": "e2767cc0-2e04-452d-9b7b-fc170e2128ec"},
      "user_profile": {
          "mapValue": {
              "fields": {
                  "age": {"integerValue": "36"},
                  "name": {"stringValue": "Andrew"},
                  "middle_name": {"nullValue": 0}
              }
          }
      }
    }, 
  "createTime": "2024-10-31T11:09:34.802575Z",
  "updateTime": "2024-10-31T12:13:36.154031Z"
}
"""
value: Document = Document.from_json(data)

d: dict = DocumentToDict(value)
print(d["fields"])

Yields:
{
  'created_at': '2024-10-31T11:09:34.760557Z',
  'session_id': 'e2767cc0-2e04-452d-9b7b-fc170e2128ec',
  'user_profile': {
    'age': 36,
    'middle_name': None,
    'name': 'Andrew'
  }
}

